# How to do I control which CMake options appear only in "advanced mode"?

Tags: cmake, build-settings

I use CMake 3.x in (more than) one of my projects. When I `ccmake .`, I get a terminal screen with various options to configure - supposedly, the ones a user might want to set manually before building. If I press `t` I enter "advanced mode", and numerous other options are visible.

Great, right? Except that some options in the non-advanced mode are such which I feel would be a better fit for the advanced mode and not be visible always (in my case it's the results of `FindCUDA.cmake`).

How can I make certain options only appear in advanced mode?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For make *CACHE* variable to be appeared in GUI (like `ccmake`) only in *advanced* mode, use command [mark_as_advanced](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.9/command/mark_as_advanced.html):

```
mark_as_advanced(my_cache_var)
```

---

Normally, `mark_as_advanced` is called by the script, which creates the variable. E.g. "Find" script marks as advanced some of variables obtained via `find_path` or `find_library`.

But it is correct to mark as "advanced" a variable created by some other script.